# Instaloader - receive media count for inputted hashtag

Tags: python, instagram, code-documentation, instaloader

I'm looking to simply input a series of hashtags and be outputted with those hashtags and their associated post count.

I believe I can use the mediacount property:
"The count of all media associated with this hashtag."
As found here: https://instaloader.github.io/module/structures.html?highlight=hashtag#instaloader.Hashtag

But am insure how to write the code for it.

I have tried:

```
from instaloader import Hashtag

Inst = Instaloader()
h = Hashtag(Inst.InstaloaderContext,"coding")
print(h.mediacount)
```

This left me with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/xxx/Hashtag.py", line 7, in <module>
    h = Hashtag(instaloader.InstaloaderContext,"coding")
  File "/xxx/instaloader/structures.py", line 1453, in __init__
    assert "name" in node
AssertionError
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

which version of instaloader APIs are you using?

I use v4.9 and the following codes can work for me

```
from instaloader import Hashtag
import instaloader

Inst = instaloader.Instaloader()
h = Hashtag.from_name(Inst.context,"coding")
print(h.mediacount)
output: 4855699
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks! I tried giving it a list but that broke that gave me an error, am I doing it the right way?

from instaloader import Hashtag
import instaloader

Inst = instaloader.Instaloader()
h = Hashtag.from_name(Inst.context,["coding", "hats"])
print(h.mediacount)

Comment: from_name() can only support str as the second argument. you need to make a list containing your hashtag strings and then iterate your list and then call from_name() with your list element    (https://instaloader.github.io/module/structures.html#instaloader.Hashtag.from_name)

Comment: I've made a list and attempted to iterate it, its giving me the first hashtag but printing the rest of the list:

list1 = ["Coding", "Hats", "Fans"]

for tag in list1:
    print(tag)

Inst = instaloader.Instaloader()
h = Hashtag.from_name(Inst.context, tag)
print(h.mediacount)

result is:
Coding
Hats
Fans
11758676

Comment: my output after running your codes: `Coding 4857399 Hats 7562182 Fans 11760370`, is that what you expect?

Comment: That's exactly what I'd expect. When I run the code my result is just the media count without the tag associated with it.

Comment: maybe you missed something, check out [the outcome of running your codes on my notebook](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n9q-IzC987Gx8og1WHy70QEWyAQUHXZv/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I missed the print(tag), thanks you!